# no peer certificate available

Tags: openssl, ldap

I'm trying to verify that my LDAP server has the proper certificates for TLS.

I went to a remote box and type:

```
openssl s_client -connect host:389 -showcerts -state
```

And the reply I got was:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
140319263606600:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake f         failure:s23_lib.c:184:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 112 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
```

It seems I don't have certs property configured, but when I type this command

```
ldapsearch -d -1 -x -LLL -ZZ
```

It seems to like my tls, I'm royally confused, can somebody clarify?

Comment: You may want to repost this in http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 4):

For StartTLS you need to use a different command line arguments.

The latest versions I had, 0.9.8.x does not have any support for StartTLS LDAP.

The http://www.openssl.org/ site was down or unavailable when I wrote this; so I can not tell if it was added in the latest versions.

The starttls option on my versions show:

```
-starttls prot - use the STARTTLS command before starting TLS
                 for those protocols that support it, where
                 'prot' defines which one to assume.  Currently,
                 only "smtp", "pop3", "imap", "ftp" and "xmpp"
                 are supported.
```

The syntax should be:

```
openssl s_client -connect remote.host:389 -starttls ldap
```

-jim